# Psycopg2 reporting pg_hba.conf error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've run into a weird situation while trying to use PostgreSQL and Psycopg2. For some reason, every time I attempt to connect to the postgre database via python, I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "steve", database "steve", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "steve", database "steve", SSL off
```

Naturally, I checked pg_hba.conf to see what the issue was, but everything appeared to be configured correctly as far as I can see:

**pg_hba.conf:**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

In addition, I've found that I can connect to the database via psql as I would expect:

```
$ psql -U steve -h 127.0.0.1
...
steve=>
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typical explanations include:

1. You are connecting to the **wrong server**.
   Is the DB server running on the same host as Python does?
2. You got the **wrong port**.
   Check the server log if you see  a connection attempt. You have to log connections for that, of course. See the [config parameter `log_connections`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CONNECTIONS).
3. You did not **reload** (SIGHUP) the server after changing `pg_hba.conf` - or reloaded the wrong cluster (if you have multiple DB clusters).

   Use [`pg_ctl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) or `pg_ctlcluser` on Debian and derivatives for that.

   Or, on modern Linux installations with `systemd` (incl. Debian & friends), typically:

   ```
    sudo systemctl reload postgresql
   ```

   Or, if there are multiple installations, check with:

   ```
    sudo systemctl status postgres*
   ```

   And then realod the one you want with something like:

   ```
    sudo systemctl reload postgresql@14-main
   ```

Comment: Embarrassingly enough for me, you're absolutely correct! For anyone who may be in a similar situation: the problem originated from upgrading from 8.4 -> 9.1. It turns out that the new server configures itself to run on 5433, awaiting a transfer of data from the old db. Check `/etc/postgre/9.1/main/postgre.conf` for the port.

Comment: @SteveGattuso: Happens to all of us. No need to be embarrassed. :) BTW, full path of the config file typically is `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for your checklist. Indeed, I had to reload. I did so using `sudo systemctl reload postgresql` on a debian 10 running postgresql 11

Comment: I am experiencing this but am not super user (and never was - I just pip installed psycopg2 and it used to work for an older database version)... Any way to do that without root access?

Answer (score 3):

I recently got into this same issue and I found the solution for this problem.

**System:**

1. I have an application server (with these packages installed `python`, `django`, `psycopg2` and `postgres client 9.6.1` (`postgresql-9.6.1.tar.gz`)), for instance `ip address 10.0.0.1`(a private address).
2. And AWS postgres RDS server "`aws_rds_host_name`" or any database IP address.

**Error:**

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host` `"10.0.0.1", user "your_user", database "your_db", SSL off`

**Solution:**

While installing the `postgres client 9.6.1` source package in application server `10.0.0.1`, we have to pass an argument "`--with-openssl`". I suggest to remove the existing the `postgres client` and install with below steps.

1. Download the `postgres client source package 9.6.1` (`postgresql-9.6.1.tar.gz`)
2. Untar the package `postgresql-9.6.1.tar.gz`.
3. `./configure --prefix="your_preferred_postgres_path_if_needed" --with-openssl (this '--with-openssl'` argument is important to get rid of that error)
4. make
5. make install
6. After successful installation, that error didn't occur when we ran the django project with `psycopg2`.

I hope this solution helps someone.

Comment: Very similar logic applies for the users of psycopg2 and any library which uses this driver under the hood (like SQLAlchemy). In order to get rid of this error you have to compile Psycopg2 with SSL support on local machine, otherwise it won't work!