# Python psycopg2, NO postgresql etc service running on mashine... Where is the postgress driver? where is pg_hba.conf? (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry)

Tags: python, psycopg2, pg-hba.conf

I am using -in Linux- python 3 and [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) to connect to some postres databases:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
connection = None
try:
    connection = pg.connect(
        user = "username",
        password = "...",
        host = "host_ip",
        port = "5432",
        database = "db_name",
    )
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Print PostgreSQL Connection properties
    print ( connection.get_dsn_parameters(),"\n")

    # Print PostgreSQL version
    cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    print("You are connected to - ", record,"\n")
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

except (Exception, pg.Error) as error :
    print ("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
```

For one of the DBs this works, but for the other I am getting:

```
Error while connecting to PostgreSQL FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", user "YYYY", database "ZZZZ", SSL off
```

I have checked the web and stackoverflow, and there are a lot of similar questions,
e.g. [Psycopg2 reporting pg_hba.conf error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693978/psycopg2-reporting-pg-hba-conf-error)

However, I am not root on the machine where I used pip/anaconda, and there seems to be no
sql service or anything similar running:

$ sudo systemctl status postgres*
$ sudo systemctl status postgres
Unit postgres.service could not be found.
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
$ sudo systemctl status post*

So none of the answers seem to be relevant, because this question seems to be based on the
postgress service running, or on the existence of `pg_hba.conf`, either of which do not in my system. Though note that a sample is included in my envs/py3/share/ (where py3 the name of my environment):

```
$ locate pg_hba.conf
/home/nick/anaconda3/envs/py3/share/pg_hba.conf.sample
```

My question here aims to -apart to find a way to solve my immediate problem- understand what psycopg2 is / how it ends up using pg_hba.conf, seemingly used in a postgresql service that does not seem to exist in my system:

**Does psycopg2 is/uses a driver? Why does it seem to include `pg_hba.conf.sample` and what is one supposed to do with it? where to place pg_hba.conf(???) it to make psycopg2 read it?**

Notes / Info based on comments:

- The DB is not locally hosted. It is running on a different server.
- I am able to access that DB using DBeaver and my local Ubuntu python, but a container (same psycopg2 version is not), so I speculate it is not a DB server issue.
- It seems  pg_hba.conf is a file that should only be on the server? (If so, that actually is part of the answer I am looking for...)

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` exists on the machine that is _hosting_ the PostgreSQL server, which apparently is not your local machine.

Comment: I believe you need to contact your DB administrator to allow you to connect to the database from your machine.

Comment: I "am" my DB Administrator :S  (my team is, and i have access though It should not be my job to change anything there) That DB is running on Azure, and so is - other container - the python that fails to access the DB. However, using the same psycopg2 version from my local ubuntu machine (again no services etc there) I can access the DB fine...! Also, using DBeaver I can access the DB without problems... So it does not seem to be a problem on the server...

Comment: 1) `psycopg2` is the driver. It uses the `libpq` library. The fact that you get the error indicates `psycopg2` is correct. 2) `pg_hba.conf` belongs on the server and is read by the server, see [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). 3) Best guess is that the`pg_hba.conf` does not have a entry for the `IP or Hostname` that the container is connecting as.

Comment: @adrian-klaver: Thanx, that was it. Seems obvious in hindsight, but so do most things. If you provide it in the form of an answer I ll accept it.

Comment: The error message: "... no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", user "YYYY", database "ZZZZ", SSL off" made it the most likely choice.